# Recursive Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to implement [this](http://www.users.csbsju.edu/~lziegler/CS331/Logical4.html) but I get a cyclic or multiple cascade path and fail to see where the problem is and how to solve it.

```
CREATE TABLE Staff(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE Supevision (
    SupervisorId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Staff(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    SupervisedId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Staff(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (SupervisorId, SupervisedId)
)
```

Comment: More specifically, you have *multiple* cascade paths, not cyclic. The error message mentions both.

Comment: You solve the error by removing the ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove one of the foreign constraint, but replace it by triggers.

```
DROP TABLE Supevision
DROP TABLE Staff


CREATE TABLE Staff(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Supevision (
    SupervisorId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Staff(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    SupervisedId INT NOT NULL --FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Staff(Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (SupervisorId, SupervisedId)
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DELETEStuff
   ON  Staff 
   FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    DELETE sv
    FROM deleted d
    INNER JOIN Supevision sv
        ON d.Id = sv.SupervisedId 

    DELETE sv
    FROM deleted d
    INNER JOIN Supevision sv
        ON d.Id = sv.SupervisorId 

END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER UPDATEStuff
   ON  Staff 
   FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Supevision
    SET SupervisedId = inserted.id
    FROM inserted, deleted
    WHERE Supevision.SupervisedId = deleted.Id 

    UPDATE Supevision
    SET SupervisorId = inserted.id
    FROM inserted, deleted
    WHERE Supevision.SupervisorId = deleted.Id 

END
GO

INSERT INTO Staff (ID)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)

INSERT INTO Supevision (SupervisorId, SupervisedId)
VALUES (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (6, 7)

DELETE FROM Staff WHERE ID = 3

UPDATE Staff SET Id = 60 WHERE Id=6

SELECT * FROM Supevision
SELECT * FROM Staff
```

Comment: How does that differ from a normal cascade?

Comment: From the point of view of final results - there will be no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try Out This:

Table : **STAFF**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staff` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Table : **Supevision**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supevision` (
  `details_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SupervisorId` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `SupervisedId` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `is` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`details_id`),
  KEY `SupervisorId` (`SupervisorId`),
  KEY `SupervisedId` (`SupervisedId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT
```

**Queries** :

```
ALTER TABLE `supevision`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `supevision_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`SupervisedId`) REFERENCES `staff` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `supevision_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SupervisorId`) REFERENCES `staff` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```